# Form repeater send wrong data with last element in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, forms

My form sends multiple forms of (name and image). However, the last element sends a name only with the wrong 'name.' Do I need to simultaneously make multiple inserts in the database to solve this problem?

1. [Form View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbR7n.png)
2. [Dump of the request with wrong last element of array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq0Vu.png)
3. [Script of repeat the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeRPh.png)

---

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <form class="form repeater-default" method="POST" 
              action="{{ route('admin.cat.doCreate2') }}"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" name="admin_id" 
                   value="{{ auth()->guard('admin')->user()->id }}">
            <div data-repeater-list="group_a">
                <div data-repeater-item>
                    <div class="row justify-content-between">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 form-group">
                            <label for="Name">Name </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" required
                                   placeholder="Enter Name of Category">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 form-group">
                            <label for="Image">Image </label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image[]">
                        </div>
                        {{-- Delete Button --}}
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group d-flex align-items-center pt-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-repeater-delete type="button"><i
                                        class="mdi mdi-x"></i>
                                Delete
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col p-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-repeater-create type="button"><i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i>
                        Add
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col p-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><i class="mdi mdi-account"></i>
                        Done
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#tableData tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), post them as text

Answer (score 0):

first solution : inputs and their labels must be on table tag and th tag and td tag
to send right data
second solution : dont use array for inputs names like name[ ] or image[ ] :

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 form-group">
<label for="Image">Image </label>
 <input type="file" class="form-control" 
 name="image">
</div>
```

and receive datas like this :

```
$data=$request->group_a
```

group_a is your data-repeater-list name :

```
<div data-repeater-list="group_a">
```

and now you can put $data in foreach and use data arrays for create ...insert and anything